# How can I display both a string and an edittext field in the same listitem?

Tags: android, android-layout

In my program I get a number of strings from a remote SQL database using json. These items (strings) at the moment populate my Listview. I would like to put an edittext field in the listview if an item comes with both a string and an edittextfield. Later on I also want to save the text that is entered in the edittext field, so I need to be able to reference it. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a view for the list as you like it to be, here is example.

home.xml

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:drawable/alert_dark_frame" >
</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

and one more xml which you have to inflate,
list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

in your activity use this method,

```
LayoutInflater mlayoutinflator;
public void getlist(final ArrayList<contact> list){
      // Get the list view
 ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    mlayoutinflator =(LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    ArrayAdapter<contact> aa = new ArrayAdapter<contact>(this, R.layout.listitem,list){
        @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView,ViewGroup parent) 
        {

                    if (null == convertView) 
                    {
        convertView = mlayoutinflator.inflate(R.layout.listitem, parent, false);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
                    holder.value1 = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                    holder.value2 = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                    convertView.setTag(holder);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                    }
                    holder.value1.setText(""+list.get(position).getName().trim());
                    holder.value2.setText(""+list.get(position).getNumber().trim());


                    convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                    {

                        public void onClick(View v) 
                        {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                            intent.setData(Uri.parse("sms:"));
                            intent.putExtra( "sms_body", list.get(position).getName()+"-"+list.get(position).getNumber() );
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    });


            return convertView;
        }
    };
    listView.setAdapter(aa);
}

 static class ViewHolder
   {
       private TextView value1;
       private TextView value2;
   }
```

Comment: very helpfull, i got most of it working now. the only thing i still don't know how to do is to reference my textboxes so i can save them.

Comment: you would have a list of strings to be added to the list. in the above get list method pass that list,now create a holder class to hold all your viewitems as in example, and nw call the view item like holder.value1.setText(yourlist.getposition.getitem)

Comment: if you have a problem drop a mail of your class i will get it fixed, raksi004@gmail.com

Answer (score 2):

Hey this might help you

[Android ListView and ListActivity](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html)